# OrderBy in another Model after a with() in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem, I'm trying to order a request by a date in a linked table.
I have a table named User and an another table named Posts in One-To-Many.

```
User::with('posts')
    ->where('last_name', 'like', $search['lastname'] . '%')
    ->where('first_name', 'like', $search['firstname'] . '%')
    ->where('email', 'like', '%' . $search['email'] . '%')
    ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('reference', 'like', $search['reference'] . '%')
            ->orderBy('date', 'asc');
    })
    ->orderBy('posts.date', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15);
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: So you wanna sort by post date and you don't care sorting order of users?

Comment: No, it's for exemple, I have a variable for sort by column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently User is the main enity and therefore sorting of posts will be among the posts OF THAT USER and not globally across all the posts.
I am guessing you want to to do a global sorting meaning posts should be sorted by their date

Try this add a new relation in User class

```
class User extends Model {
  public function rpost() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\where\ever\posts::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    //inverse mapping from user --> posts table
    //assuming posts table is using user_id column to track the ownership
    //and user table has id as it's primary key
  }
}
```

Then modify your code

```
User::with('rpost')
    ->select('posts.title'.'posts.id', 'users.name',  
           \DB::raw('(SELECT posts.date FROM posts WHERE user.id = posts.user_id ) as sort'))
    ->where('last_name', 'like', $search['lastname'] . '%')
    ->where('first_name', 'like', $search['firstname'] . '%')
    ->where('email', 'like', '%' . $search['email'] . '%')
    ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('reference', 'like', $search['reference'] . '%');
    })
    ->orderBy('sort')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sortBy

```
 $users = User::with('posts')->get()
  ->sortBy(function($user) { 
     return $user->posts->created_at;
  })
```

or you can use joins like this with orderBy

```
  $query = User::where('last_name', 'like', $search['lastname'] . '%')->where(
        'first_name',
        'like',
        $search['firstname'] . '%'
    )->where('customers.email', 'like', '%' . $search['email'] . '%');
    $query = $query->join('posts', 'posts.user_id','=','users.id');
    $query = $query->select('posts*','users.*');
    $query = $query->orderBy('posts.created_at','asc');
    $record = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it was not working... I want to order by posts.created_at
The request give me a duplicate of User when he has multiple post, I want to get One User and his Posts, like the result of with()